# Break if function argument has a certain value

Tags: c, gdb

I have a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char *str = "Hello World";

   printf("foo\n");
   printf("bar\n");
   printf("%s\n", str);

   return 0;
}
```

How can i set breakpoint in gdb in order to stop program if argument passed to printf starts with a value "bar"?

PS. Program has compiled with no debug symbols:

```
$ gcc prog.c
```

Comment: Are you trying to set a break point inside printf?

Comment: *"PS. Program has compiled with no debug symbols"* - if you know what debug symbols are, and that you aren't getting them in your compile...what exactly were you planning on doing after you hit the breakpoint?

Comment: William Purcell: hmm i didn't try, but it sounds interesting :)
HostileFork: this is only simple example. The long story is: i have a compiled program (tcp server) and i don't have a source. I would like explain some of protocol messages. For example i see in tcpdump something like:

command.4441.3.5000.abc\0

i know that: 4441 is my process PID, 3 is length of "abc", but i don't know what is 5000 so i would like to disassemble some part of binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no debug symbols, I think you'll need to do something very low-level, like

```
(gdb) break printf if (*(char *)$rdi == 'b' && *(char *)(1+$rdi) == 'a' && *(char *)(2+$rdi) == 'r' )
```

or

```
(gdb) break printf if (((char *)$rdi)[0] == 'b' && ((char *)$rdi)[1] == 'a' && ((char *)$rdi)[2] == 'r' )
```

Keep in mind that some systems will change `printf("bar\n")` into a call to `puts("bar\n")`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. It's very useful for me. What about longer strings? Can we use strcmp for string compare like:

... if (strcmp($rdi, "foobar") == 0)

???

Comment: @y3ti Yes, if there's a strcmp in the running image, then you can call it. If not, you'll get an error like **warning: failed to reevaluate condition for breakpoint 1: No symbol "strcmp" in current context.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that talks about setting break points on conditions: 
http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_34.html#SEC34

Comment: You should copy the relevant text from the link in your answer. Otherwise, if that link ever decays, as links tend to do, your answer becomes useless.